# Ошибка при компиляции проекта в Android Studio

Tags: java, android, apache

Устанавливаю библиотеки `ApacheHttp` в `build.gradle`, нигде ничего не подчеркивает, но при компиляции выдаёт ошибку.

Код в `build.gradle` :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сама ошибка :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно исправить ошибку?

Comment: Добавьте ваш код и ошибку в тело вопрос в виде текста, а не изображений.

Answer (score 1):

Конфликт в последних 2 строчках. Удалите и замените на

```
android{
    ...
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

P.S. А лучше используйте `HttpURLConnection`.

Comment: Warning:Unable to find optional library: org.apache.http.legacy

Answer (score 1):

Помню сперва то же намучился с этим. Потом подключил библиотеку вот так

```
dependencies {
    //compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
    compile files('libs/json-20090211.jar')
}
```

в итоге работает.

Comment: Не подгружает:import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;